# Unique 2D array columns permutations

Tags: arrays, node.js, algorithm

I have the following function

```
function permutation(a){
    let res = [];
    for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        let restA = a.slice(0,i).concat(a.slice(i+1));
        let rest = permutation(restA);
        if(rest.length === 0){
            res.push([a[i]]);
        }else{
            for(let j=0; j<rest.length; j++){
                res.push([a[i]].concat(rest[j]));
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

which generates all permutations of 1D array with unique values like `[1,2,3,4]`.

I also have a 2D array filled with zeroes and ones like this

```
[
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
]
```

I need to generate all *unique* permutations of this array. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the fact it's a 2D array and consider this a 64 bit value with 34 1's and 30 0's. With every valid combination of these bits you can build a unique 2D array (8 bits per row).

However, if you do the math you'd see it's not really feasible to create all these combinations:

[64! / ( 34! * 30!) = 1.620288e+18](https://www.google.com/search?q=64!%2F(34!*30!))

This is almost as large as unsigned 64 bit range ([1.8e+19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing)) - it's practically a 10th of that.

---

Having said that, if you really want to do this, just iterate a 64 bit unsigned integer from 0 up to MAXVALUE, and test "on" bit count in each iteration - if it's 34, you've found a valid combination.